# Indian passport with less than 6 months validity

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, transit, indian-citizens, dxb

I am an Indian citizen residing in USA and I will be traveling to India in March 2017. My Indian passport will have five and a half months validity when I come back to USA after my India trip. My green card is valid till 2021.

Will I have any issues with Immigration in India / US while coming back?

Also, I am flying Emirates through Dubai as a transit.

Will I have any issues with Emirates or authorities at Dubai since my passport will have less than six months validity?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a passport to enter the US - your Green card is enough and simply has to be valid.

Source: [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=us&SECTION=PA&SUBSECTION=00&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), the database used by airlines.

> Passport exemptions: Passengers with a Permanent Resident/Resident Alien Card
>     (Form I-551).

and

> Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to
>      residents of USA must be valid on arrival.

As for Dubai, you're not entering the UAE, so they have no additional requirements for you.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have an [unexpired green card](https://www.uscis.gov/green-card/after-green-card-granted/international-travel-permanent-resident), you will not be denied entry into the United States after your trip, even if your [passport is expired](https://www.quora.com/How-do-expired-passports-affect-U-S-green-card-holders). However, your airline might have different requirements regarding your passport upon your return. So although you won't have issues entering the country, you may have issues boarding your plane. I would call Emirates Airlines to confirm.

Comment: The ability to use only a green card to enter the US is well known, and it is listed in Timatic.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Not among all clerks. A guy I know, who holds a Dutch ID card and green card, was denied boarding on a Delta flight from Paris to New York. After I contacted the clerks at CDG airport and made them discover they'd been wrong, he got put on the next flight plus a hefty compensation

Answer (score 1):

Maybe consider looking for [*Tatkaal Passport Applications*](http://www.passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqTatkaalPassports) where in best case scenarios, when in India you get a new passport issued in a matter of 2 to 3 days.

I think you are eligible for a Tatkaal Passport. You can verify your status in [Page 8, 9, 10 of the Application Form](http://www.passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/pdf/ApplicationformInstructionBooklet-V3.0.pdf) which states cases where one is eligible for the aforementioned passport.

You could even drop an email or visit your nearest Indian Consulate General for a much clear resolution to your query.

Comment: As OP is resident in US, can he avail tatkal service from consulate? A [cursory search](http://www.immihelp.com/nri/indianpassport/tatkal-passport.html) shows it may not be straightforward.

Comment: I agree that the above mentioned passport service is more of a hassle than a boon.